# DNS Resolution Issue - Error 105

Tags: networking, dns, connection, network-adapter, ipv6

I cannot connect to the internet.

I am having issues resolving DNS (Error 105) in all browsers on my Dell XPS 15 laptop running Windows 8 64x. There is also a dual boot with linux Mint running that has the same issue. I am studying abroad this semester and now that I have landed in Austria I have this issue. Everything worked just fine two days ago in the states, but I have a hard time believing that the locale is the source of this issue.

There is no modem in the room for me to power cycle or reset. Also my roommate can connect just fine with his MacBook Air and his Windows 7 VM. I can see other computers on the network and in the properties of my adapter it states that IPv4 has internet but IPv6 has no internet. Currently I am using my roommates usb network adapter to post this, so that works. I have narrowed the issue down to the network adapter since the problem persists through both linux and windows.

Also I should note that yesterday after I reset all my advanced settings in 'Internet Options' I had connection, although it was slow. After a computer restart the issue came back, and any attempt at recreating the solution did not work. So it could be an intermittent DNS issue as well.

Here are the steps that I have taken:

- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /release & renew
- re intsall network adapter driver
- reset netwokr adapter (linux and windows)
- used malwarebytes and ccleaner
- set DNS to google's public    DNS
- Turned off firewall
- Changed computer and group name
- Tried with ipv6 off

Here are the results from a ipconfig /all in windows:

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Ocelot

Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :

Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid

IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 8C-A9-82-7B-3E-AC

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 14-FE-B5-AF-41-6B

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 193.170.132.193(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0

Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, February 28, 2013 1:06:28 AM

Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, February 28, 2013 2:06:28 AM

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 193.170.132.1

DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 193.170.132.5

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 140.78.2.62    140.78.3.62

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Also I went into the logs and found a few interesting errors and warnings. -The ICS_IPV6 failed to configure IPv6 stack. Event ID: 34001

AND

-The name "WORKGROUP :1d" could not be registered on the interface with IP address 193.170.132.193. The computer with the IP address 193.170.132.202 did not allow the name to be claimed by this computer. Event ID: 4321

I am running out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, since you can get online with other network adapters, but not this one (the Realtek whatever-it-is) the problem is isolated to that adapter or its settings.

So first, check the obvious:

1. Go to **Network and Sharing Center** by right-clicking the network icon in your system tray.
2. Then go to **Change adapter settings**.
3. Find the adapter in the list, right-click it and choose **Properties**.
4. In the properties, click on **Internet Protocol version 4** then click the **Properties** button.
5. Ensure that **Obtain an IP address automatically** and **Obtain DNS server addresses automatically** are both selected.
6. Click **OK** to exit any open windows, until you return to your list of adapters.
7. Now try your connection again.

If this doesn't help, you'll want to go to Plan B: Nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.

1. In the list of adapters, right-click the one corresponding to the non-functioning Realtek adapter, then click **Delete**. Confirm that you really do want to delete it.
2. Open **Control Panel**, **System and Security**, then **Device Manager**.
3. In Device Manager, expand the **Network adapters** line item, and look for your **Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller**. (If it is *absent*, skip this step. But be careful, the name might be slightly different.) Right-click on it, and choose **Uninstall**. Confirm that you really do want to uninstall it.
4. Without closing the Device Manager window, connect to the Internet through your secondary network adapter (e.g. the USB network adapter you borrowed from your roommate).
5. On the Device Manager **Action** menu, choose **Scan for hardware changes**. Windows will reinstall the device drivers for your network card. If necessary, it will obtain them from the Internet through your secondary connection.
6. Try connecting to the Internet via your built in network card.

If it *still* fails, you might have a hardware issue with the network adapter. In that case, seek help from your computer manufacturer.

P.S. The most likely cause of that *other* error is that there's another computer named OCELOT somewhere in student housing. Feel free to ignore it, rename your computer, or find the other guy and make him rename his computer. :)

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I have ensured that both the IPv4 and IPv6 are set to acquire IP and DNS automatically. After that I deleted the driver and installed directly from Dell's website. The issue persists.

Also I renamed my computer and group again to something entirely different. This did not work either.

I don't believe that is a hardware issue (and certainly hope not) because intermittently the computer will connect to the internet. Most times I just get a DNS error. Also I am able to view other computers that are the network and windows will say 'Connected' 'Internet Access'